# CKEditor with Simple Image Browser plugin

Tags: javascript, json, ckeditor

I'm trying to use CKEditor with the Simple Image Browser plugin on wampserver, but I'm sorry, I really do not understand what to put in this line:

```
CKEDITOR.config.simpleImageBrowserURL
```

In the video he putted a php file, what to put in this file ?
(video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WB5Y8XNQlgE)

I'd like to show the pictures that are in a variable directory 'images/$id/'

Thanks for your help.

Page of the plugin:
http://ckeditor.com/addon/simple-image-browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `simpleImageBrowserURL` you need to provide a URL (e.g. a php script) which delivers the content as JSON.

You can start with a URL to a static .txt file with a content like this:

```
[{"url": "/images/1234/image1.png"},{"url": "/images/1234/image2.png"}]
```

Or a very simple php script:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$id = '1234';
echo '[';
echo '{"url": "/images/' . $id . '/image1.png"},';
echo '{"url": "/images/' . $id . '/image2.png"}';
echo ']';
?>
```

**UPDATE**

With the above php script the simple image browser plugin does not load the images. This is caused by the jQuery `$.get` function the plugin uses. While jQuery already parses the JSON and passes objects to the function the plugin tries to parse the objects (here the `images` variable):

```
$.get(CKEDITOR.config.simpleImageBrowserURL, function(images) {
      var json;
      console.log(images);
      json = $.parseJSON(images); // this will not work if the images parameter contains objects
```

It may be that this worked that way with older versions of jQuery...

So to make this work the php script has to deliver a `text/plain` mime type:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
$id = '1234';
echo '[';
echo '{"url": "/images/' . $id . '/image1.png"},';
echo '{"url": "/images/' . $id . '/image2.png"}';
echo ']';
?>
```

Comment: Sorry but it doesnt work:

here is my file 'image-list.php':
<code>
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
?>
[{ url: 'http://i1-win.softpedia-static.com/screenshots/Simple-Browser_1.png' }]
</code>

And i have this ok:
CKEDITOR.config.simpleImageBrowserURL = 'images-liste.php';

But none image appears in the list...
Thanks for your help...

Comment: If your php file name is *image-list.php* you should write `CKEDITOR.config.simpleImageBrowserURL = 'image-list.php'`, not *image-liste.php*

Comment: sorry, i wrote it right the first time, i was wrong here: CKEDITOR.config.simpleImageBrowserURL = 'images-liste.php'; and my file name is images-liste.php too. Is there a way to be sure the connextion in made ? thanks so much.

Comment: Is there any error in the javascript console or the web server's error.log?

Comment: It might be this:
Uncaught Error: [CKEDITOR.resourceManager.add] The resource name "simple-image-browser" is already registered.
But i dont know what it means exatly...

Comment: I don't think that *already registered* is a critical error. But to be safe you might build a fresh ckeditor (including your desired plugins) here: http://ckeditor.com/builder

Comment: Please consider the update of my answer concerning the mime type of the php script. And don't forget to include jQuery. I finally got the plugin working.

Comment: Its what i did, but i really think the plugin have problems. I tried to make it in every way but it doesnt work. I'll put my code here and the errors i have... Thanks

Comment: I think your original question has been answered. If you have other problems regarding setup of ckeditor you should start a new question.

Comment: I didnt find a solution, then i changed the script in ckeditor... one that make a the same... Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/ckeditor/plugins/simple-image-browser/plugin.js"></script>

    <link href="styles/knacss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="styles/ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="styles/fonts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="styles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script>
    $(function () {
        CKEDITOR.config.extraPlugins = 'simple-image-browser';
        CKEDITOR.config.simpleImageBrowserURL = 'images-liste.php';

        CKEDITOR.replace('details');
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p><label for="description">Descripção:</label></p>
    <p><textarea class="ckeditor" name="description" id="description"></textarea></p>
</body>
</html>
```

images-liste.php:

```
    <?php header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo '[';
echo '{"url": "http://andrewprokos.com/wp-content/uploads/22346-brasilia-cathedral-night-2.jpg"},';
echo '{"url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6c/Brazil.Brasilia.01.jpg"}';
echo ']';                                                                   
?>
```

Errors:

- ckeditor.js:327 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getEditor' of undefined
- ckeditor.js:610 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined